# How to extract number from string in BATCH and get total of all numbers?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to extract only response time from ping command.

For example:

> ping 127.0.0.1

should show

> > 1
> >     1
> >     1
> >     1

instead of

> > Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
> >     Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
> >     Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
> >     Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

I tried to get solution from google, but i get one command which is:

> ping 127.0.0.1 | for /f "tokens=5" %i in ('findstr Reply') do @echo %i

It shows output like:

> > time<1ms
> >     time<1ms
> >     time<1ms
> >     time<1ms

I would like to extract 1 from it.

Also If possible I want to calculate total of all the response time.

Comment: You could extract 1 by becoming more finicky with the for /f command; but there's no way in heck that you're going to compute a total using just default Windows batch commands.  Your best bet is to bring in a real scripting language, like Perl, VBScript or Powershell.

Comment: @RossPresser It's a one liner, Ross. :)  See below.

Comment: (facepalm) I should have known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works here:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=4 delims=Replyfrombytes=time<ms" %%a in ('ping 127.0.0.1 ^|find "TTL" ') do echo %%a&set /a c=c+%%a
echo Total=%c%
pause
```

Comment: even, if this is language dependent - I like your way of thinking different ^^

Answer (score 1):

something like this :

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set $total=0
for /f "tokens=5" %%i in ('ping 127.0.0.1 ^|findstr Reply') do (
set $var=%%i
set $var=!$var:time^<=!
set $var=!$var:ms=!
echo !$var!
set /a $total=!$total!+!$var!)
echo !$total!
```